# which artwork dimension to use for mobile app design

Tags: adobe-photoshop, interface-design, resolution, android, ios

I am designing app for ios and android in photoshop.
I know I must export graphics to 3@, 2@, 1@ for ios and mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi for android.
But I do not know, what size of artwork should I start with? (dimensions, width x height)

I think better will be to start with bigger artboard and the downsample each image to specific output size. But because of so many resolutions and sizes of displays, which size should I pick for ios and which for android?

Comment: Always start big/high and then export/save smaller.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe just avoid using Photoshop to design user interfaces/apps.  With the best will in the world, Photoshop isn't designed for this. It's a photo editor.

Adobe has XD (for Mac and Windows). It's vector based more like Illustrator in some ways. Try that instead (and believe it or not, it's actually free). There are also other similar applications out there worth a look: Sketch (Mac only), Figma, Lunacy by Icons8 (Windows only), etc.

XD has all the resolution presets built in to the Export Assets panel, since that's what it's designed for.

Screenshots from Adobe XD Export Assets dialog.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Update: Lunacy is multi-platform now.

Answer (score 1):

Photoshop is not so popular any more with app designers, because it basicly remains a photo editor with poor typography and alignment features, and not well optimized for an UI workflow. Use a more modern wireframing tool like Sketch, Figma, Invision or (Adobe's own) XD and these will come with built-in presets for devices and automation in downsampling the artwork.